# How to filter items inside “ngFor” loop, based on object property string

Tags: string, angular, typescript, filter, ngfor

I need to filter items inside an `ngFor` loop, by changing the category in a drop-down list. Therefore, when a particular category is selected from the list, it should only list the items containing that same category.

HTML Template:

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let model of models">{{model.category}}</option>
</select>

<ul class="models">
  <li *ngFor="let model of models" (click)="gotoDetail(model)">
  <img [src]="model.image"/>
  {{model.name}},{{model.category}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Items Array:

```ts
export var MODELS: Model[] = [
{ id: 1, 
  name: 'Model 1', 
  image: 'img1', 
  category: 'Cat1', 
},

{ id: 2, 
  name: 'Model 2', 
  image: 'img2', 
  category: 'Cat3',
},

{ id: 3, 
  name: 'Model 3', 
  image: 'img3', 
  category: 'Cat1',
},
{ id: 4, 
  name: 'Model 4', 
  image: 'img4', 
  category: 'Cat4',
},

...
];
```

Also, the drop-down list contains repeated category names. It is necessary for it to list only unique categories (strings).

I know that creating a custom pipe would be the right way to do this, but I don't know how to write one.

Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:2GZg5pLaPWKrsD2JRted?p=preview

Comment: Why not do this filtering *in the component code?* You could do e.g. `*ngFor="let model of filteredModels"` and write `get filteredModels() { ... }` to provide it. You could do the same thing to give an array of unique entries for the `select` element.

Comment: *"I know that creating a custom pipe would be the right way to do this"* - what led you to that conclusion? *"but I don't know how to write one"* - then have you considered *learning?*

Comment: Sure jonrsharpe :).  I'm a novice at this and I hope that I will find the right way. I read a lot of posts about filtering the angular 2, custom pipes are mainly referred as the right choice ..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a sample pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'matchesCategory'
})
export class MathcesCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Array<any>, category: string): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => item.category === category);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
<li *ngFor="let model; of models | matchesCategory:model.category" (click)="gotoDetail(model)">
```

===== for the plunkr example ====

You need your select changes to reflect in some variable

First define in your class a member:

```
selectedCategory: string;
```

then update your template:

```
<select (change)="selectedCategory = $event.target.value">
   <option *ngFor="let model of models ">{{model.category}}</option>
</select>
```

last, use the pipe:

```
  <li *ngFor="let model; of models | matchesCategory:selectedCategory" (click)="gotoDetail(model)">
```

==== comments after seeing the plunker ====

I noticed you used promise. Angular2 is more rxjs oriented. So the first thing I'd change is in your service, replace:

```
getModels(): Promise<Model[]> {
  return Promise.resolve(MODELS);
}
```

to:

```
getModels(): Observable<Array<Model>> {
  return Promise.resolve(MODELS);
}
```

and

```
getModels(id: number): Observable<Model> {
  return getModels().map(models => models.find(model.id === id);
}
```

then in your `ModelsComponent`

```
models$: Observable<Array<Model>> = svc.getModels();
uniqueCategories$: Observable<Array<Model>> = this.models$
  .map(models => models.map(model => model.category)
  .map(categories => Array.from(new Set(categories)));
```

Your options will become:

```
     <option *ngFor="let category; of uniqueCategories$ | async">{{model.category}}</option>
```

and your list:

```
      <li *ngFor="let model; of models$ | async | matchesCategory:selectedCategory" (click)="gotoDetail(model)">
```

This is a very drafty solution since you have many duplicates and you keep querying the service. Take this as a starting point and query the service only once, then derive specific values from the result you got.

If you'd like to keep you code, just implement a UniqueValuesPipe, its transform will get a single parameter and filter it to return unique categories using the `Array.from(new Set(...))`. You will need though to map it to strings (categories) first.

Comment: Thanks Meir,  i'll try to implement this code into my project, to see if it gives result. I will get back to you... thx

Comment: Meir, when i tried to filter items by using this code, console throws me an error "Cannot read property 'category' of undefined"

Comment: add a break point (or console.log(items, category) at the top of the function and see it gets the values right

Comment: and if this doesn't work, put your full implementation on plnkr so I can have a look

Comment: Found the problem, your select is not bound, i.e. changes do not update any value. Will edit the answer

Comment: Great job Meir,  it works! I marked answer as correct, still i need one last thing. Is it possible to have only unique categories in dropdown list, not to get same names repeated?

Comment: Thanks Meir, i will try to do with your code. Regards

Comment: thx. I don't think I posted a plunker. I commented on the original one. Can you please refer me to the link?

Comment: you've got a typo in `MathcesCategoryPipe` (Mat**hc**es)